# how to resolve Undefined index error?

Tags: php

hey guys i got following error
Undefined index: hname in C:\Temp\5Aug2010\job.php on line 38

this error occur in insert command
i use

```
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['hname'])."'
```

where hname is a textbox field on form

if i use

```
'".mysql_real_escape_string((isset($_POST['hname'])))."'
```

then error will gone but in database it show empty field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to stay inside that string you quote, use

```
 ".(!empty($_POST['hname']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['hname']) : null)."
```

but for readability's sake, it would be nicer to do before outputting the string:

```
 if (!empty($_POST['hname']))
  $hname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['hname']);
 else
  $hname = null;
```

Comment: it still cant save value in db

Comment: $insert = "INSERT INTO jobs (hname,discription,url,adddate)
VALUES ('".(!empty($_POST['hname']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['hname']) : null)."','".nl2br(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['discription']))."','".mysql_real_escape_string((isset($_POST['url'])))."','".mysql_real_escape_string($adddate)."')";
$add_jobs = mysql_query($insert) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$insert);

Comment: @Partik the finished SQL query.

Comment: & main thing is that "discription" also one of the field on the form but its value save into db without any error.

Comment: @Pratik please show the finished SQL query with the values in it.

Comment: id : 5
hname: blank
discription:Walk-in interview for php web developers in VISION....
url:blank
adddate:2010-08-13

Comment: @Pratik the finished SQL query containing INSERT INTO.... the string you get when doing `echo $insert;`

Comment: INSERT INTO jobs (hname,discription,url,adddate) VALUES ('','Walk-in interview for php web developers in VISION SOFT+.\r\nfor more detail visit our site.','','2010-08-13')

Comment: @Pratik Sorry, I can't see anything wrong with that query! What is the exact error message?

Comment: ya but main thing is that "discription" also one of the field on the form but its value save into db without any error